# Intent data passing error

Tags: android, android-intent

I am trying to pass in a user input from one page to another in an android application using intents. There is a button in the app that takes in user input and then after an on click event sends it to another page.The program goes something like this:

### MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity{   EditText sendData;
Button toIntent;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    sendData=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.sendData);
    toIntent=(Button)findViewById(R.id.toIntent);
    toIntent.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Activity2.class);
            String toSend = sendData.getText().toString();
            i.putExtra("Display", toSend);
            startActivity(i);
            }
    });
}
```

### Activity2.java

public class Activity2 extends Activity {

```
TextView act2;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity2);
    String defaultName = "";

    Intent i2 = getIntent();
    Bundle extras = i2.getExtras();
    if(extras!=null)
    {
        defaultName=extras.getString("Display");
        act2.setText(defaultName);
    }



    }

}
```

The error that keeps up popping is:

> 03-27 07:34:34.554: E/AndroidRuntime(3058): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>   03-27 07:34:34.554: E/AndroidRuntime(3058): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.intentslinkin/com.example.intentslinkin.Activity2}: java.lang.NullPointerException
>   03-27 07:34:34.554: E/AndroidRuntime(3058): at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2180)
>   03-27 07:34:34.554: E/AndroidRuntime(3058): at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
>   03-27 07:34:34.554: E/AndroidRuntime(3058): at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
>   03-27 07:34:34.554: E/AndroidRuntime(3058): at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
>   03-27 07:34:34.554: E/AndroidRuntime(3058): at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
>   03-27 07:34:34.554: E/AndroidRuntime(3058): at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
>   03-27 07:34:34.554: E/AndroidRuntime(3058): at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
>   03-27 07:34:34.554: E/AndroidRuntime(3058): at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>   03-27 07:34:34.554: E/AndroidRuntime(3058): at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
>   03-27 07:34:34.554: E/AndroidRuntime(3058): at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
>   03-27 07:34:34.554: E/AndroidRuntime(3058): at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
>   03-27 07:34:34.554: E/AndroidRuntime(3058): at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
>   03-27 07:34:34.554: E/AndroidRuntime(3058): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
>   03-27 07:34:34.554: E/AndroidRuntime(3058): at com.example.intentslinkin.Activity2.onCreate(Activity2.java:23)
>   03-27 07:34:34.554: E/AndroidRuntime(3058): at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
>   03-27 07:34:34.554: E/AndroidRuntime(3058): at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
>   03-27 07:34:34.554: E/AndroidRuntime(3058): at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144)
>   03-27 07:34:34.554: E/AndroidRuntime(3058): ... 11 more

Somebody please help.

Comment: oh no ... sorry ... silly mistake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't initialize your TextView (NullPointerException)

```
TextView act2;
```